# How to query data using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, between

I wanted to query data using between clause like this

```
select * from timerecords where empid=? and date between ? and ?
```

I just have to do it in rails. I have this code and I want the program to display in json format redirecting to localhost/timerecords.

```
  def showtimerecords
   empid=params[:empid]
   startdate=params[:date]
   enddate =params[:date]

   render json: @timerecords=Timerecords.where(empid: empid,
                                :date => startdate..enddate)
   #redirect_to @timerecords
  end
```

When I type http://localhost:3000/timerecords/showtimerecords/empid=2&startdate=2015-03-26&enddate=2015-03-27

It says,

```
(No route matches [GET] "/timerecords/showtimerecords/empid=2&startdate=2015-03-26&enddate=2015-03-27")
```

Here's my config/route.rb code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'timerecords/showtimerecords'
 get 'timerecords/index'
 get 'employees/index'
 get 'employees/show'
 get 'employees/new'
 get 'welcome/index'
 root :to => 'employees#new'
 resources :timerecords, :employees
 post 'employees/update_info'
 post 'timerecords/update_time'
end
```

Comment: Please, add your *config/routes.rb*

Comment: Can you post the link that you are using here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are typing it wrong, it should look like this, the parameters should start with a `?`, try using the following link

```
http://localhost:3000/timerecords/showtimerecords?empid=2&startdate=2015-03-26&enddate=2015-03-27
```

Also, you are sending `startdate` and `enddate` parameters but you are accessing using `date`, modify your code as mentioned below

```
def showtimerecords
   empid=params[:empid]
   startdate=params[:startdate].to_date
   enddate =params[:enddate].to_date

   @timerecords = Timerecords.where(empid: empid,
                                :date => startdate..enddate) 

   render json: @timerecords
   redirect_to 'timerecords/index'
end
```

Comment: when i type that, it says wrong number of arguments

Comment: here's the new error... undefined method `Timerecords' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/timerecords_controller.rb:16:in `showtimerecords'
#16 code is this
render json: @timerecords.Timerecords.where(empid: empid,
     :date => startdate..enddate)

Comment: it is now solved. no error, thanks..but my recent problem is that this does not output anything.. it's blank despite of having 2 records in the database

Comment: Its because records with the conditions you passed do not exist